# How to ask a user multiple questions in if statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm programming this code and I have a main menu with options and one of the options is taking a survey. I'm not sure how to have the user take the survey if they choose the "take survey option".

I know I need to use `if` and `elif` statements, but I'm not sure how I would incorporate the survey within the `if` statement.

Here's the code so far:

```
print(“Welcome to the Happy Tails Website!”)
print("*** Main Menu ***")
options = input("A.Take a survey B. Learn about surrenders C. Learn more about Happy Tails Animal Shelter D. Exit")
```

Comment: Don't use curly quotes in code.

Comment: `if options = 'A': take_survey()`

Comment: what does the "take_survey()" do exactly?

Comment: It's the function that implements taking the survey.

Comment: So it can print all the survey questions, get the user's responses, save the results, etc.

Comment: So would I put all the survey questions is equal to "take_survey()"

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that. It doesn't need to return anything, so there's nothing to check equality with.

Comment: I mean how would the function ask the user the questions

Comment: It can use the `input()` function, just like the main menu does.

Answer (score 0):

Put all the survey questions in a list. Then you can make a dictionary of questions and answers.

```
print("Thank you for taking the survey")
questions = ["Text of question 1", "Text of question 2", "Text of question 3"]
responses = {}
for q in questions:
    answer = input(q)
    responses[q] = answer
```

After this you can save the `responses` dictionary somewhere.